# Creating Hyperlinks in real time chat messages using Node.js UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: results.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have created an application with real time chat application using socket.io and NodeJs and was wondering how to create hyperlinks within my chat. I have the source code to run. The problem is when i send a message, It does not want to convert to a hyperlink and remain as rich/plain text. also if you look at the code below.. It seems to look fine but i am getting a server side response error: messages.forEach is not a function. is there any suggestions or advise of a better way to get it to change my text to a hyperlink?

```
    router.get("/:chatId/messages", async (req, res, next) => {
  const messages = await Message.find({chat: req.params.id})
    .populate("sender")
    .then((results) => res.status(200).send(results))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.sendStatus(400);
    })
   messages.forEach(message => { // ADDING LINKS TO CHAT MESSAGES
 
        if(message.content != null) {
            const postBody = message.content
 
            const textToArr = postBody.split(" ")
 
            textToArr.forEach((word, index) => {
                if(word.match(/\bhttps?/i)) {
                    word = `<a href="${word}" target="_blank" title="Click to go to link">${word}</a>`
                    textToArr[index] = word
                }
                else if(!word.match(/\bhttps?/i) && word.indexOf("www") !== -1) {
                    word = `<a href="https://${word}" target="_blank" title="Click to go to link">${word}</a>`
                    textToArr[index] = word
                }
            })
 
            message.content = textToArr.join(" ")
        }
    })
    res.status(200).send(messages)
    
});
```

Comment: Are you sure `messages` is an array?

Comment: Hi, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Log your `messages` variable to check if it is an array.